# Woocommerce Product import API uploads featured images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cdn, cloudflare, woocommerce-rest-api

My requirement is that I import products to my store using woocommerce API.
I have multiple store setup so that I have placed my product images in CDN server. But the issue I am facing is when I import products using our tool it uploads images to server and set them in media library.
I do not want it to be uploaded to media library. Just want it to use CDN image url so that it can work over multiple sites and product import timing also gets reduced.
I have used **Featured Image from Url** plugin but want it to be included as product import option.

Can anyone guide me what should I do in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endpoint:
http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products

Basic POST:

```
{
    "name": "Featured Image from URL",
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "key": "fifu_image_url",
            "value": "http://ps.w.org/featured-image-from-url/assets/icon-256x256.png"
        },    
        {
            "key": "fifu_image_alt",
            "value": "Logo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello Marcel I have one question.
Can I add size based multiple images using this plugin and API. I will create different sized images in my CDN. So that all size images work for a product.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The plugin works with 1 URL only. There is a Premium version that allows to do what you want, but your images need to be hosted on Flickr. The plugin settings has more information about that.